# Printing to stdout without the involvement of functions

Tags: c, function, io, stdout

How can one print some arbitrary text on-screen without the call to any function ?

---

Another way of asking this question is how are i/o functions implemented ?

---

I tried searching in google, but unluckily, no result was found similarly to as if it was some sort of a top secret thing.

For study purposes.
*I personally don't feel even close to a real programmer without knowing this.*

Comment: They're done by making system calls. The underlying mechanism is OS-dependent, and hidden in the system libraries, so you need to use a function to do it.

Comment: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)

Comment: Since C is cross-platform PL it is understandable that it is OS-dependent. Do you mean the standard lib's `system` function ?

Comment: You cannot. Because `main` already **is** a function and gets called.

Comment: No, I mean functions like `read()` on POSIX systems.

Comment: Inside that function, it performs a special instruction that calls into the OS kernel.

Comment: Use a bare-metal embedded system.

Comment: @Malina Have you read the Wiki I linked to?

Comment: Now I did, it mentioned `fork` which as AFAIK for creating a process. I find it for quite confusing from this point in consideration. Like why don't I have such control and these functions do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in the end, loosely speaking, the low level software in the computer sets a special memory location or uses a special instruction that changes the voltage on some pins on the CPU, and the hardware responds to these changes.

But user-level processes don't have access to those instructions or memory locations.  Messing with stuff that drives the hardware is the responsibility of "device drivers" that execute in the kernel.  They use these special memory locations or instructions, and each one is given responsibility over a particular hardware device.

User-level processes communicate with device drivers via system calls as mentioned in the comments.  A system call is not quite like a normal function call -- you don't just call the code.  After setting up a "request" for what it wants to do, the user-level process pokes the kernel, usually by using a software interrupt instruction.  The kernel wakes up, looks at what you request, and then decides itself what code to execute.  The kernel code runs at a higher privilege level and will call directly into the device drivers that access the hardware.

This is how the kernel keeps processes safe from each other.

To actually get from stdout to the screen is a lengthy process:

- the standard library ends up making a system call that writes to a "pipe" that is attached to stdout.  This is where it leaves your process.
- The other end of the pipe is being read by the console.  The console is a user-level process, so it has to do a system call to do the reading.
- The console decides what to display, and how to make it visible to you. There will be a bunch more layers, but eventually there will be system calls into drivers that control the graphics hardware.  They will mess with the bits that turn into pixels on the screen, making your text visible.

Comment: Ah I see. I hoped that it would be something far more simple and implementable by any chances.

Comment: Not unless you're running DOS.

Comment: In the early days of home computers, you used to be able to do this stuff yourself.  I have fond memories of rendering images by poking data into memory locations whose bits were made directly visible as pixels on the screen.

Comment: I think this is possible even now as long as you succeed to run your code as if you were running in OS-non-protected mode, then call the BIOS interrupt

Comment: Well, you can always write your own kernel or code for embedded systems instead of big computers.   If you're running DOS inside windows or linux, though, you can run the same code you used to run, but it's an illusion -- you don't really control the hardward

Comment: That consumes time for more than one worker I presume. And it is very unlikely that it will worth it.

Comment: Not at all!  There are fantastic (and cheap!) single-board computers that you can program over USB.  In a lot of these you have direct control over the hardware, and lots of them have displays

Comment: Really? This sounds awesome. Wait, but isn't it the same if I just don't install OS on my PC and boot up the compiler stuff and the minimum for programming ?

Comment: @Malina Of course -- how do you think the OS itself is programmed?

Comment: Then why do I need SBC.. I can control hardware just without running the OS. I believe it would be a lot easier too. And a lot kernel-panic-prone too.

Comment: You need the OS to run your editors and compilers and IDEs, so if you're going to be programming directly to the hardware without an OS, it works better if it's a different computer.  The other computer doesn't have to be an SBC, but SBCs are made for this, so it's easier, and easier to connect other devices

Comment: Thanks. Well I only need a very simple text editor, could be with a console interface and the c compiler or interpreter depending on what I am willing to do.

Comment: Both the editor and the compiler are major projects.  I think the editor would be much simplier than the compiler)   Expect to write hundreds of  source and header files each with their own problems to be debugged.  In the end, expect (at least) 100,000 lines of code  And for that much code you will need a `configuration control` system, the compiler that you will use to generate your own utilities, an indepth understanding of editing     and a lot lot more.  Unless you plan on making your living writing editors and/or compilers,  Your time would be better spent  learing